# Windows Forms C# Tool location is not same

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

I'm developing an windows forms application using .NET C# and so far all code related are just fine. But, I got some UI trouble. I have this gauge that I'm using in the UI for displaying a connection speed but theres one problem. When I develop the application on an workstation with Visual Studio 2010 and makes the design and then keeps developing the application on another workstation with Visual Studio 2012 some tools and widgets like the gauge seems to not have the same location in the UI anymore.

It's like if the resolution had been changed, but It hasn't. It's 1920 x 1080 on both workstations. The form's window size is fixed and can't be changed or maximized. Most of the controls fit pretty good on both workstations but this gauge is not fiting good.

The one reason why it matters is because the background of the page where the gauge is placed are using the gauge for an overlay of the background so it's really important that it is placed on the exact same spot on both workstations. Any suggestions why this issue maybe comes up? I don't think that the problem is the gauge more like some settings to the widgets or the main form.

Comment: Have you checked bot workstations DPI settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the `AutoScaleMode` property of your `Form`.  The default value of this property (`AutoScaleMode.Font`) can cause the form to adjust its size and the positioning of child controls depending on the user's system font sizes.  If you change this property to `AutoScaleMode.None` then the form will not attempt to resize itself.  If you perform any GDI+ drawing in your application, though, you need to make sure that all the drawing calls are DPI independent.  Also note that changing this setting may make your application hard to see for users with poor eyesight (or tiny monitors).

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that both of the workstations did not have the exact same DPI settings. Changing both of them to the same value did solve the problem.